# Как при переходе на следующий шаг сцены, изменять сообщение предыдущего? Telegraf WizardScene. NodeJS

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

В моем проекте есть WizardScene вида

```
const superWizard = new WizardScene('super-wizard',
  (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('Step 1')
    ctx.wizard.next()
  },
  (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('Step 2')
    ctx.wizard.next()
  },
  (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('Done')
    ctx.scene.leave()
  }
)
```

Как мне при переходе на следующий шаг не отсылать новое сообщение, а изменять уже существующие?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)